# How Get Discount-Percentage In C#

Tags: c#, percentage

let suppose dis.text = 2, prc.text = 100, I am using these codes.It Should be 
net_prc.text = 98.But its giving me -100.Can anybody tell me why?,And how can i get correct
discounted percentage??

```
 private void net_prcTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int d;
        int di;
        int i;
        d = Convert.ToInt32(dis.Text);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(prc.Text);
        di = -((d / 100) * i) + i;
        net_prc.Text = di.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I don't feel like pondering right now. Can you tell me what the values are for dis.Text and prc.Text.

Comment: `let suppose dis.text = 2, prc.text = 100` @MikeC.

Comment: Convert int to decimal... it will work....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your division, `d / 100`, is a division of integers, and it returns an integer, probably `0` (zero). This is certainly the case with your example `d = 2`.

**Addition:** If you really want to do this with integers (rather than changing to `decimal` or `double` like many other answers recommend), consider changing the sub-expression

```
((d / 100) * i)
```

into

```
((d * i) / 100)
```

because it will give you a better precision to do the division as the last operation. With the numbers of your example, `d=2` and `i=100`, the first sub-expression will give `0*100` or `0`, while the changed sub-expression yields `200/100` which will be `2`. However, you will not get rounding to nearest integer; instead you will get truncating (fractional part is discarded no matter if it's close to `1`).

Comment: yep its giving me 100 or 0.then how can i do this ??

Comment: @MuhammadAzeemKhan Add a decimal point to one of your values, and change the type of di, to a double.

Comment: @ChrisCooney
OK i got it.The problem is solved, Thanks.But Now if i enter dis.text = 1.5, Its giving me Error "the input string was not in correct format".

Comment: That's because you're parsing Int32. Int32 values do not have decimal places.

Comment: @ChrisCooney SO what to do now ??

Comment: My guess would be to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx)

Comment: @MuhammadAzeemKhan Check my addition to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

`di = -((d / 100) * i) + i;`

All values in this statement are Integers. You are going to be computing arithmetic with decimal places, and you need to increase the precision of your variables to a double or a float. Instead, add a decimal place to one of the values in the equation. This will force all values into doubles.

This is a process called [Arithmetic Promotion](http://www.dotnetperls.com/numeric-promotion). It is where, at run time, the precision of every variable in an equation is increased to the size of the most precise variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try (d / 100.0) to force it to use floating point arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it would be, changing the datatype of `di` to `float`

```
di = (d * 100) / i;
```

Comment: If `d` and `i` are still integers, the above division will still be an integer division. It doesn't matter that it is later assigned (hence converted) to a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

C# has an odd way of doing maths, because your numbers are cast as integers, you can only do integer math with them. you need to initially have them as float or as double so you can do float math or anything at all that requires a decimal place within the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Even dis.text = 1.5

```
private void net_prcTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double d;
        double di;
        double i;
        d = Convert.ToDouble(dis.Text);
        i = Convert.ToDouble(prc.Text); 
        di = -((d * 100.0) / i ) + i;
        net_prc.Text = di.ToString();
    }
```